# Someone is using a lot of bandwith through OpenVPN, how can I find out who?

Tags: centos, iptables, logging, openvpn

I just checked bandwith usage on SolusVM and it was 250gb in 2 days, and I know it's one of my users through OpenVPN.

I think it is a torrent because it is upload + download 24/7.

I want to find out who is doing this by getting their username. I make accounts for every user on my VPN ( adduser name -s /bin/false/nologin ).

Is it possible to see who is uploading? I need to get the username or subnet ( like 10.8.1.1 ).

Comment: No offense, but you probably should have figured this kind of thing out before starting a VPN business.

Answer (score 2):

Use tcpdump to identify the source IP of the traffic, then look through your OpenVPN logs to see who that IP address was given to.

Comment: There is a lot of connections from the torrents. I need to be able to filter it so that I can see who uploads the most.

Comment: So grab all of the source IPs and see which one is the most active.

Answer (score 1):

Check the (default) `/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status` file. If the user is connected you'll see the `bytes_sent` and `bytes_received` columns. These columns reset if an user (re)connects though.